# 7zip incorrect command line error?

Tags: compression, 7zip, archiving

Following the syntax guide here: http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/update.htm

The following code *should* be correct - at least it looks syntatically correct. But when I run it I get the error "incorrect command line" - meaning a syntax error. Does anyone know what is wrong with this?

I am using 7zip version 9.20.

```
7z u H:\archive.7z -up0q3r2x2y2z1w2!H:\update-february.7z
```

Comment: shouldn't it archive the files from the current directory?

Comment: My understanding is that 7zip automatically archives all the files from the current directory in the command line. If this is wrong, can you please provide info on how to correct it?

Comment: I recheck this with 7zip 9.20 (both: x86 and x64). Yes, it does not require to specify files to archive. But your command line work fine for me without any error.

Comment: alright thanks Ill look into it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add "endlocal" before 7z command:

```
endlocal
7z u H:\archive.7z -up0q3r2x2y2z1w2!H:\update-february.7z
```

The error was due to `!` in 7z command line, when used `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`

Answer (score 0):

I got the error when I separated -o switch from the actual output directory. They need to be together `-o"$CI_PROJECT_DIR` not `-o "$CI_PROJECT_DIR`. With 7z you get a much better Error Message "Switch too short"
[image]